# Angular Test - How do I mock the "history.state.value" object in my test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-router

I have an error when running my component default test as shown in the image
[image]

I am not sure how to mock that object - to give a bit more details, from my home component I redirect to the WelcomeComponent as follows:

```
this._router.navigate(['/welcome'], { state: { value: this.myForm.value } });
```

and in the WelcomeComponent I grab the value.

How do I mock that state? Thanks

Comment: I think you want to use *this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state* not *history* in your component.  Then you want to use RouterTestingModule in your test, setup a route, and then navigate to that route in your test.

Answer (score 0):

`history` is a dependency in your code. Therefore, it should be injected as a dependency, for example, as `WINDOW` - as a global token.

```js
export const HISTORY = new InjectionToken<typeof history>('HISTORY', {
  factory: () => history,
  providedIn: 'root',
});
```

Now you need to update your code to inject `history` as a token:

```js
export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {
  formata = this.history.state.value;
  //        ^^^^^ add this. here

  constructor(@Inject(HISTORY) public readonly history: typeof history) {}
  //          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ inject the token as your dependency

  // the rest of your class.
```

Profit. Now you can mock the token in tests and spy its methods.

```js
  // declaring a mock
  const mockHistory = {
    state: {
      value: {}, // <-- mock value is here
    },
  };

  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [WelcomeComponent],
    providers: [
      {
        provider: UsenService,
        useValue: mockUserService,
      },
      {
        provider: HISTORY, // <-- add this
        useValue: mockHistory, // <-- add this
      },
    ],
    imports: [HttpClientModule],
  }).compileComponents();
```